# Gravity Forms- How do I separate individual fields from one form into separate entries based on field names

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am tasked with two things, taking inventory of hundreds of pieces of equipment and allowing users to find specific pieces of that equipment to see when the last time an inspection has been done on them.

I have a form that uses conditional logic to populate different fields based on what is selected. For example, my parts list is comprised of "Power unit", "Extension", "Base", etc. When someone clicks on "Power Unit", another field pops up with "Unit A", "Unit B", etc. When someone clicks on "Extension", another fields pops up with the length of the extension, "10ft", "5ft", ect. Then it populates another field of "left", "right", or "universal". The final field to pop up on any given piece of equipment is a unique 1 to 3 digit number, but an "Extension / 10ft / left / #115" and a "Power Unit / Unit A / 115" could exist, so the numbers are only unique to individual categories of equipment.

I know that I can view entries of this form and search for a specific piece of equipment in the submitted form entry, but is there a way that I can create a separate folder for each category, "Power unit", "Extension", "Base", and have the fields automatically separated and sent to those folders from the one form.

So I could have a completed form entry with:

Power Unit - Unit B - #110

Base - Unit B - #02

Extension - 10ft - left - #07

Extension - 10ft - right - #10

Extension - 5ft - left - #03

Extension - 2.5ft - right - #09

I could "view entry" and look to see if "Power Unit - Unit A - #02" is in this entry only to find it is not and then search other entries (which could be hundreds) only to find it has not been inspected yet. I could also use the search function, but with the different variances between different pieces of equipment, this may not be ideal for the average user.

I would like to have other entries, along with the main one, populated automatically into categories, like this, so I only need to click on a category of equipment, not a list of all equipment:

Power Unit - Unit A

```
#17
#20
#167
```

Power Unit - Unit B

```
#15
#190
```

Extension - 10ft - left

```
#34
```

Extension - 10ft - right

```
#20
#45
```

As of right now, I created multiple folders in DropBox that correspond to each piece of equipment, then I take a PDF of the whole entry and place them in each folder, (So for a normal entry, this form is placed in 10-20 different folders) then go in each PDF and circle the piece of equipment so that someone can go in and physically see that the item is in fact in the PDF. As you can tell, this is tedious and I would like a more automated solution.

I'm not sure if I explained that correctly, but I really do appreciate anyone who reads all this and can point me in some direction that allow me to get started on this. Thank you so much!!!